# Idon not know what to do .when i export to aab it results in the following error

Tags: build.gradle, godot, gradlew

editor/export/editor_export_platform.h:182 - Export: Building of Android project failed, check output for the error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\gamefaar\android\build\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\1s6fi1dqibye7m7s90j9wk0n1).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 65

i tried to update my java to 21 gradle to 8.0.0 like ext.versions = [
androidGradlePlugin: '8.0.0',
compileSdk         : 33,
// Also update 'platform/android/export/export_plugin.cpp#OPENGL_MIN_SDK_VERSION'
minSdk             : 21,
// Also update 'platform/android/export/export_plugin.cpp#DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION'
targetSdk          : 33,
buildTools         : '33.0.2',
kotlinVersion      : '1.7.10',
fragmentVersion    : '1.3.6',
nexusPublishVersion: '1.1.0',
javaVersion        : 21,
// Also update 'platform/android/detect.py#get_ndk_version()' when this is updated.
ndkVersion         : '23.2.8568313'
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
but one become other.please help..